# Adding Place to Facebook Feed Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog, feed

When posting to /me/feed, it's possible to add a page id of location with "place". This results in a post as a check in that shows the message with a map of the location.

Adding "place" as a query string parameter to the feed form at facebook.com/dialog/feed doesn't seem to add the location to the post. Is there a way to use /dialog/feed and add a location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing on FB group, it looks like only message, picture, and place work to make a checkin with a location. If adding other parameters like caption or link, it turns into a regular feed post without a location. This is unfortunate because without a link back to the app, there is almost no incentive to make a checkin from an app.

Comment: from where do i can get place id.

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide your code.

This is my code, and it's working:

```
$post_url = '/' . $user . '/feed';

$msg_body = array(
    'message' => 'message for user timeline',
    'place' => '106339232734991',
);

// posting on user page feed
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
```

Comment: Yes, that work but once you add source, caption, etc, it no longer makes it a checkin and turns it into a feed post without a location. I think this is by design.

Comment: I think "source" and "caption" are fields to post photos, if so the post url should be the following: $post_url = '/' . $album_id . '/photos';

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/428651263853608 - “javascript ui feed dialog - place parameter does not work”

Response from Facebook:

> 'place' is not a supported parameter per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/.
>
> Status changed to **By Design**